# Checking program for crashes

Tags: c++, unit-testing, crash, try-catch

I am writing a program which does unit testing via the CUTE library and have a function which just needs to be checked if the program crashes when calling it.
I'v already tried a `try-catch` block like :

```
try 
    {
      myfunc();
    }
catch(...)
    {
    }
```

But this just handles exceptions and is of no use when no exception is called (i.e. `abort()` ). 
So is there a way to just check if there is a crash resp. informing me where the crash happened (line number, ...)?

Comment: Try this, By handling SIGABRT 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910865/c-abort-override

Comment: You want to know where the crash occurred before the crash occurs and prevent the program from crashing? What you writing a Superman Program or Prince of Persia time machine?

Comment: Okay, I really thought wrong. I wanted to somehow let the function crash 'safe', enabling me to get a message afterwards, but after thinking on this again I realized the impossibility.
But thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

By handling SIGABRT. Or maybe register your handler via atexit functions (see also 
[c++ abort override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910865/c-abort-override))

Comment: Thank you, but it seems you got me wrong. I meant I would like to make sure program doesn't crash, the `abort()` issue was just an example.

Comment: when you handle SIGABRT , you avoid the default behaviour , that is killing the program

Comment: i meant similarly you might want to handle other signals like SEGV, etc

Comment: @user1612880: Not observed as an offense actually; just nit picking ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the debugger in your IDE. Or else, use a debugging tool like **GDB** or **Valgrind**.