# Linking Windows Debugger to Project

Tags: debugging, linker, visual-studio-debugging

i coded a big project that runs when I open it in Debug or Release Mode, but when i open it without Debugging (ctrl + f5) it crashs. I searched a long time to find the heap error, but didnt find anything. The problem is i need the running .exe of the programm, so i wanted to ask if there is a possibility to link the windows debugger to the .exe so it always starts with it.

Comment: Do you get any feedback when it crashes? An error message/ An assert firing?

Comment: No, after 3 - 5seconds, but I think I have more than one error. No it just don't answer, when I open it with application verifier it gives back an abort()

Comment: Can you write some tests round specific functions to try to flush out which one is failing?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't crash right away, maybe this helps:

1. You can run the executable.
2. Open your solution in visual studio. Make sure it's the same build.
3. Open the DEBUG menu and click attach to process.
4. A window will open, listing all processes that are running. Select the executable that's crashing
5. Click the DEBUG menu again and select Exceptions (ctrl-alt-E)
6. Make sure the checkbox "Thrown" is checked for Common Language Runtime Exceptions
7. Now crash your application.. It will halt at the line that causes it.

Also look for environment directives. like #IF DEBUG  #END IF. or #IF RELEASE That kind of stuff. Tricked me a couple of times too..

Good luck. Hope this helps!

Comment: It crashes after 3 -  5 seconds

Comment: You will have to click really fast I'm afraid.. I'm sorry my answer wasn't too helpful. Good luck, I hope you find what causes the crash.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't help, I even tried application verifier, but It just gives back a abort. I'm so depressed, I would even pay someone to fix this error...

Comment: If I could get the code somewhere, I can't promise you that I'll find the bug.. But I wouldn't mind trying to debug it for you...

Answer (score 0):

You can do various things. First make sure you have a "big out try block" in main. i.e. put the main logic in a try can catch exceptions and report these clearly. This probably isn't what's happening in your case.

You can attach a debugger - including Visual Studio, to a running process - see the "Attach to process" option under the debug menu. If it's built with debug symbols, which you can do, even for release code this may help. If it's optimised you may find it difficult though.

Finally, you could generate a crash dump and inspect that after it's failed. See docs on [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360.aspx). There are several examples on its [usage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/05/19/prolific-usage-of-minidumpwritedump-automating-crash-dump-analysis-part-0.aspx). Or you can install an abort handler: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910865/c-abort-override). This mentions `_set_abort_behavior` which if invoked with `_CALL_REPORTFAULT` will generate a crash dump too.